# Supported Html elements by Excel

Tags: html, excel

Recently I found out that if you save some html markup as an xls it will open up in Excel just fine with all your styling. Example

myfile.xls

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td style="background: red;text-align:center;border:1px solid;"><h1>Blah</h1></td>
            <td style="background: red;text-align:left;font-weight:bold;">Blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3221312dsdasd</td>
            <td>hahah2123dedaah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>123456</td>
            <td>hahah2123dedaah</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I was wondering if there is any kind of documentation on this about what html and CSS Excel supports and what it doesn't? I tried using Google and really couldn't find much. I was mostly interested in creating multiple worksheets.

Comment: I doubt there is a way to automatically generate worksheets from HTML. Also, all styles must be inline. There is no support for an external stylesheet.

Comment: If you need Excel files with multiple sheets then as noted by Diodeus this approach will not work. you could instead try the "XML spreadsheet" approach: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;285891

Comment: If you still want more info on styling the basic <table></table> approach, you can find it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa155477

Comment: Thanks Tim that was the most helpful comment. Based on that it looks like it has to be split up into separate files if you want multiple worksheets. @Diodeus you can define styles and use them in the head element if you include it; so they do not have to be inline styles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some in-depth information regarding the HTML approach to creating Excel files with sample code see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kaushikborah28/79Nick08302007171404PM/79Nick.aspx

Also checkout the official documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa155477%28office.10%29.aspx

Other options to create Excel files:

MS provides the OpenXML SDK V 2.0 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx

This can read+write MS Office files (including Excel).

Another option see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx

IF you need more like rendering, formulas etc. then there are different free and commercial libraries like [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/), [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx), [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/), [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) etc.

Comment: Official documentation is offline now; go [here](https://stigmortenmyre.no/mso/) instead (or [here](https://www.rodriguezcommaj.com/blog/dial-ed-for-mso) to download)