# Writing to an excel file - Performance Analysis

Tags: java, performance, apache, excel, jexcelapi

So after doing some research on writing to an Excel file i have found that both the Apache API and JExcel could cause performance issues. At the moment my application outputs the information i want to a TextArea but i was considering writing to an excel file instead of copying and pasting (an option that is built into the application - i have a button that copies to the clipboard) to one. My question is : should i include an option to write to an excel file or should i continue to use the copy to clipboard option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to export data, use csv (or tab delineated).  If you need formatting, you might use HTML, with an xls extension: [Supported Html elements by Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881948/supported-html-elements-by-excel)

If you need to *import* from a true Excel file, you'll need to use a library.