# white-space: pre; ignored/inconsistent inside <td> in export to (save as) .xls

Tags: html, css, excel, export-to-excel, html-table

consider the following, in a browser:

```
<tr>
   <td><pre>My  ex       tra   whitespace is    preserved</pre></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td style="white-space: pre;">My  ex       tra   whitespace is    preserved</td>
</tr>
```

But in excel, when I open the above .html file, the extra whitespaces are removed unless I use `<pre>`

This is a problem because one table I'm exporting has 50 columns and ~2000 rows. This not only balloons the size of the file (which would be fine), but also causes excel to crash.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

[image: inconsistency]

Comment: A related question, [Supported Html elements by Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7881948/1281433), asks about what CSS is supported by Excel.  The links in those answers may or may not described whether `white-space` is supported. Here's an off-site question whose answers contain some more links,  [Cannot get Excel CSS formatting to stick when opening HTML table](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/574fe748-9a9a-4ec9-ab61-2eed1ab0562d/cannot-get-excel-css-formatting-to-stick-when-opening-html-table).

Comment: The MSDN article, [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx) claims that Word supports `white-space`, though doesn't directly address Excel.

Comment: We are seeing different behavior even in excel for how it exports a simple spreadsheet with spaces. The Microsoft Office HTML and XML Reference guide says blocks of white spaces should be wrapped in a span with the `mso-spacerun:yes` style attribute .. but even this isn't functioning as expected. We have tried using `&nbsp;` but this causes other issues because Excel reads this as ASCII 160, which SSIS obviously reads differently than a normal space.

Comment: To clarify the previous comment about SSIS .. this Excel doc was being exported (from the DB) for the users to modify, then upload, back to the server, which would stick it on a queue for SSIS to process and load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the pre tags to wrap the tds like this:

```
<tr>
    <pre>
    <td>My  ex       tra   whitespace is    preserved</td>
    <td>My  ex       tra   whitespace is    preserved</td>
    <td>My  ex       tra   whitespace is    preserved</td>
    </pre>
</tr>
```

It worked just fine. I used on a 2000 line HTML table with 6 columns.

Comment: If this works, it probably shouldn't, as it breaks standards: "**Element `<pre>` cannot be nested inside element `<tr>`.**" and also "**Element `<td>` cannot be nested inside element `<pre>`.**" Similarly, you cannot nest `<table>` or `<tr>` inside `<pre>` either. All that said, I would be curious to try this to compare browser compatibility & performance (when Excel tries to load it), but I no longer work with that codebase. ¬_¬